# NGINX + HHVM + Magento

Tags: magento, nginx, hhvm

I've been working on a development box deploying an Nginx, Magento, HHVM model.  The site loads nicely and I don't get any real clear errors that I can see.  However, a good number of my images are not loading properly.  All I get are the image dimensions.  The version of HHVM I'm using is:

```
HipHop VM 3.3.0-dev (rel)
Compiler: heads/master-0-g39d07abf36f7cad883d6be2a384a77c0c8aac040
Repo schema: 248cb6ce2d336c890fb26fd16690bf1b53b46994
Extension API: 20140829
```

The version of Nginx is:

> nginx version: nginx/1.7.4

Some images load, and others don't.  We're using timthumb for images, and I do see one error:

\nWarning: Is a directory in /home/user/shared/timthumb/index.php on line 90

If I run a curl from the command-line, I get the following result for an image, which means it's being seen as far as I can tell:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: image/gif
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By: HHVM/3.3.0-dev
CF-Cache-Status: HIT
CF-RAY: 16513733df33085c-IAD
Server: cloudflare-nginx
Date: Fri, 05 Sep 2014 08:56:47 GMT
Expires: Sun, 05 Oct 2014 08:56:47 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=2592000
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d6c188df6595a443200995301f0b707981409907407975; expires=Mon, 23-Dec-2019 23:50:00 GMT; path=/; domain=.placehold.it; HttpOnly
Last-Modified: Fri, 19 Nov 2010 07:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=31536000, public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate
```

I have a separate test server with the same content/database running NGINX/PHP-FPM, and the only variable I can see that's different in the curl is that when I run the curl against the dev server running php-fpm, the result is Content-Type: image/jpeg.  When I run it against HHVM I get Content-Type: image/gif.

I would think this is related to rewrite rules, but I'm not sure.  I also just discovered this error here as well in exception.log:

```
2014-09-05T12:04:06+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: open(tcp://127.0.0.1:11211?persistent=1&weight=2&timeout=10&retry_interval=10/sess_dd885307c2ba602e5faa7020c9c7c038, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2)  in  on line 0
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is my server.ini file
pid = /var/run/hhvm/pid

hhvm.server.port = 9000
hhvm.server.type = fastcgi
hhvm.server.default_document = index.php
hhvm.log.use_log_file = true
hhvm.log.file = /var/log/hhvm/error.log
hhvm.repo.central.path = /var/run/hhvm/hhvm.hhbc
hhvm.enable_static_content_from_disk = true
This is what I used to fire up HHVM  sudo hhvm --mode daemon -c /etc/hhvm/server.ini -vServer.Type=fastcgi -vServer.Port=9000

Comment: Images in different areas load properly.  However in logs, timthumb images look like this,

92.253.79.54 - - [05/Sep/2014:14:45:10 +0000] "GET /timthumb/catalog/category/306/325/0/0/1612_Square_LR_4.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 1267 "http://i.domainname.com/en_jo/catalog/category/view/s/all-sales/id/7/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0"

Comment: FYI : `tcp://127.0.0.1:11211` this mean that magento trying to connect to memcached server

Comment: Have you tried seeing what curl returns with Cloudflare disabled?

Comment: Skin images, media, or both?

Comment: I haven't actually.  I wasn't aware that cloudflare would have anything to do with it.  It's just strange to me that everything works fine with php5-fpm.  Wouldn't this be more along the lines of a rewrite rule? How would I disable cloudlare for testng?

Comment: My apologies for not updating the thread.  It appears that cloudflare is not detecting images properly.  It brings back a content-type of gif for a jpg file.  Does anyone have any experience with this? I'm still researching.